# Conda install r-topicmodels package fail

Tags: r, rstudio, conda

I am trying to install the `topicmodels` package for R using `conda`. According the [link](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-topicmodels) I put follow command to console:

```
conda install -c conda-forge r-topicmodels
```

But I have an error:

```
Solving environment: failed
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
- r-profvis
- r-topicmodels
```

As I see `profvis` is the build-in package of RStudio. Removing it, it causes removal of the RStudio.

How can I install the `topicmodels` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear Stack Overflow community,

I have solved my problem. To use the `topicmodels` package I installed an older version of RStudio (1.0.153 instead of 1.1.423). There is no build-in `profvis` package.